# DockerHub API - listing tags

Tags: docker, docker-registry, dockerhub

I'm trying to get the list of tags for a public image in DockerHub.

I found the following example which works:
`https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/${reposiroty}/tags`

but it's paged, and I need to control the page size and I can't find documentation on this API. It says v2 in the URL, but it does not look like the V2 spec, neither like v1. 
The registry v2 spec seems to require authentication which i'm not interested in because I only query public data. https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/

So if someone knows how to get the entire list of tags in one request from Docker Hub, please share.
Also if Someone can shed some light on the poorly documented Docker Hub API, it'll help.

Comment: It helps a bit to keep the development console open while nagivating on docker hub. As it is a single-page application, you can observe the API calls in the network panel.

Comment: please change the URL above to '_https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/${reposiroty}/tags'

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can add the query parameter `page_size=X` to determine how many tags will be displayed.  It won't automatically give you every tag, but you can set it to a really big number to ensure you get what you want.

```
https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/ubuntu/tags?page_size=1000
```

Comment: Thanks you. What threw me off originally is that the response always comes back with `count: 50` regardless of the page size parameter, I guess that's a bug

Comment: The `count` key in the response should be the total number of tags in the repository.  Are you sure there are more than 50 tags in the repository?  The Ubuntu example I gave back always returns the same number "324" regardless of whether I use page_size=10, or page_size=1000.

Comment: I just needed to know that "library" is what you use to get to the official images.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example way to retrieve all the tags associated with ubuntu docker image:

https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/ubuntu/tags

Credits to Simon in the comments.

Comment: have you red the question at all? i've edited it to clarify the question is about controlling page size

Comment: How do i do it for private repository in docker hub ?